# We need tags for our site!

Tags: discussion

We need tags so people can responsibly ask questions, and so that we can better answer questions as well. What tags should we have?

Answer (score 15):

Mainly tags happen as needed. We really don't need to worry about them, they'll happen organically as questions are asked. One good thing is that during private beta everyone can make tags.

Also since tags are dumped if they have no questions we can't really pre-make them anyways.

Comment: What Nick said. We just have to watch out for tags that are effectively synonyms, but that will have to happen as we go along as well.

Comment: Also worth being aware that tag messes will happen. They're inevitable. It'll take some effort on the community's part to retag some things, eventually. But that's part of the organic growing pains of a new SE site.